# How do I create a NAMED PROPERTY (Not Displayed by default)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an Advanced Function in with "Named Property" which is a property that is not displayed in the default output. I have been trying to find the syntax with no luck. CMDlets have these. You have to use Get-Member to discover them.

Thanks for your help

Comment: can you maybe give an example of what you are talking about? I almost wonder if you are talking about input parameters to the function?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "NoteProperty"?

`Add-Member` allows you to add members dynamically to your objects.  Check out `help add-member`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure how formatting is displayed, you would need to create a format.ps1xml file and load that formatting file after you create your function. Probably the best way to do this would be in a module and include the formatting file the module manifest (psd1) file.

To get more information, check out help about_format.ps1xml and help Update-FormatData

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't display by default because it is not specified in the formatting file of the object's type (ps1xml). You can still see it if you pipe to format-* and specify all properties ('*').